# Typescripts Errors on Angular 12 with Material 12

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I updated to Angular 12 (And Ang Material 12) today following the guide lines provided by Angular at https://update.angular.io/. Since then I am getting a number of errors on that all relate to Angular Material. There are 71 of these errors that appear on the Visual Studio 2019 Error Window. Here is an example of one of the errors:

“Class 'MatButton' incorrectly implements interface 'CanColor'.  Type 'MatButton' is missing the following properties from type 'CanColor': color, defaultColor”

Here is an example of a class

```
/**
 * Material design button.
 */
export declare class MatButton extends _MatButtonBase implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy, CanDisable, CanColor, CanDisableRipple, FocusableOption {
    private _focusMonitor;
    _animationMode: string;
    /** Whether the button is round. */
    readonly isRoundButton: boolean;
    /** Whether the button is icon button. */
    readonly isIconButton: boolean;
    /** Reference to the MatRipple instance of the button. */
    ripple: MatRipple;
    constructor(elementRef: ElementRef, _focusMonitor: FocusMonitor, _animationMode: string);
    ngAfterViewInit(): void;
    ngOnDestroy(): void;
    /** Focuses the button. */
    focus(origin?: FocusOrigin, options?: FocusOptions): void;
    _getHostElement(): any;
    _isRippleDisabled(): boolean;
    /** Gets whether the button has one of the given attributes. */
    _hasHostAttributes(...attributes: string[]): boolean;
    static ngAcceptInputType_disabled: BooleanInput;
    static ngAcceptInputType_disableRipple: BooleanInput;
    static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<MatButton, [null, null, { optional: true; }]>;
    static ɵcmp: ɵngcc0.ɵɵComponentDeclaration<MatButton, "button[mat-button], button[mat-raised-button], button[mat-icon-button],             button[mat-fab], button[mat-mini-fab], button[mat-stroked-button],             button[mat-flat-button]", ["matButton"], { "disabled": "disabled"; "disableRipple": "disableRipple"; "color": "color"; }, {}, never, ["*"]>;
}
```

All the errors are pretty much the same as the one above just pointing to different classes. I suspect it relates to the tsconfig settings, but there seems to be no mention of this in anywhere on the internet.

Note the Angular App builds and runs 100% fine. These are errors showing up on the IDE. The app seems to run fine though. Here are my tsconfig files:

Note these errors did not show up when running on version 11.1

**tsconfig.json**

```
  {
      "extends": "./tsconfig.base.json"
      //"files": [],
      //"references": [
      //  {
      //    "path": "./src/tsconfig.app.json"
      //  },
      //  {
      //    "path": "./src/tsconfig.spec.json"
      //  }
      //]
    }
```

**tsconfig.base.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "importHelpers": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "module": "es2020",
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }

}
```

**Tsconfig.app.json**

```
{
  "extends":  "../tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./",  
    "types": [ "node" ]
  },
  "files": [
    "main.ts",
    "polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Here is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "hizuko-web-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "bundle-report": "webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/stats.json",
    "build-prod": "ng build --configuration production --aot"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "12.1.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "12.1.1",
    "@angular/cli": "12.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "12.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "12.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "12.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "12.1.1",
    "@angular/material": "12.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "12.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "12.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "12.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "12.1.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^12.1.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "chart.js": "2.9.3",
    "core-js": "3.6.2",
    "rxjs": "6.6.2",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^8.4.1",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "12.1.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "12.1.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-cli": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "source-map-explorer": "^2.3.1",
    "ts-node": "~8.5.4",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "4.2",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.6.0"
  }
}
```

Here is my environment
[image]

Can anybody help with this?
Thanks

Comment: Hello, please, post one of the class with the error.

Comment: I updated the post above with the class. Not sure how to past the code in the comment, it does not allow me

Comment: Is it one of your class or a Angular Material class? Maybe just refresh somehow your IDE?

Comment: All the errors relate to Angular Material Classes, no custom classes. I have restarted VS multiple times. Run NPM Install a few times.

Comment: I created a new angular 12 project and run it with angular material - no errors occured. Did u try to delete node_modules folder, do npm install and then ng serve?

Answer (score 0):

Try updating `ts-node` to the latest version.

Comment: Ok so up updated Visual Studio from 16.81 to 16.10 and the problem went away. Not sure what changed in the update.